# Growth of finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

**Background.**  There is an important group-theoretic notion of **[growth rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory))**, defined for  finitely-generated groups $G$ equipped fixed finite generating sets $S$. The growth rate is (the equivalence class of) the function $\gamma_{G,S}(n)$ "counting" the number of vertices in the ball of radius $n$ in the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to the generating set $S$. For instance, one of the foundational results in this direction is [Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth).

Much is known about  functions $\gamma_{G,S}(n)$ but much remains unknown.

**Question:**

> What is known about growth rates of sequences of finite groups?

A bit more precisely:

> What is known  about asymptotics of the sequences $\gamma_{G_i,S_i}(n_i)$, for various classes of  sequences $(G_i)$ of finite groups satisfying $|G_i|\to\infty$?

I am especially interested in the setting when all finite groups $G_i$ are simple. What is known about growth rates in this case?

Comment: Is $S$ a *set* of generators, perhaps $S = \{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$?

Comment: Yes S={s_1,....,s_n}.

Comment: Well, it is asymptotically constant because the group is finite. There is a meaningful question here only if you consider some sequence of finite simple groups.

Comment: If I consider a particular family of finite simple groups, then the complete characterization was done or it is still unanswered

Comment: This post was created pursuant to the [Guidelines on context edits and rewrites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites).  The text of this question was written by @MoisheKohan.  The question was originally asked by  
Lokenath Kundu.

Comment: The function $\gamma_{G,S}$ is not independent of $S$. Only its behaviour when $n \to \infty$ is independent of $S$. However, for a finite group $G$, $\gamma_{G,S}$ is eventually constant

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez I suggest, you read the question and the answer a bit more closely. But, yes, what you wrote is absolutely correct.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I read your answer and I like the way it is written because you emphasize on the importance of the $S_i$, which is something the OP or other user might be missing out, so I just wanted to point it out

Answer (score 6):

To expand my comment:

In order to form a meaningful question along these lines, one has to consider an infinite sequence of finite groups $G_i$ with generating sets $S_i$, such that $|G_i|\to\infty$. Then one would define an asymptotic growth functions of this family $\gamma(n)$ and study its asymptotics (rate of growth) in relation to group-theoretic properties of the groups $G_i$. One example of this approach is the article

*Black, Sarah*, [*Asymptotic growth of finite groups*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1998.7502), J. Algebra 209, No. 2, 402-426 (1998). [ZBL0922.20036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0922.20036).

Her setup is to fix a uniform bound on cardinalities of the generating sets $S_i$ and define
$$
\gamma(n):= \sup_i \gamma_{G_i,S_i}(n). 
$$

Then she gets some interesting results which imply, for instance, that in the case of finite simple groups growth cannot be (sub)polynomial.   She conjectures that for sequences of finite nonabelian simple groups, growth is (totally) exponential, i.e. exponential regardless of the choices of bounded generating sets and proves  some interesting results towards this conjecture.